# GameScene does not have a member named spawnPipes

Tags: swift

```
let spawn = SKAction.runBlock({() in self.spawnPipes()})
```

Пишет ошибку

> GameScene does not have a member named spawnPipes

Как исправить?

Comment: @Anonymus, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Такое происходит, когда в первой же строке блока запускаешь функцию или другой блок, который возвращает значение, отличное от описанного в блоке высшего уровня, то есть у `runBlock () -> Void` тип возвращаемого значения `Void`, а ваша функция `spawnPipes()` возвращает что-то иное. В данном случае такая конструкция в принципе неверна, поскольку `runBlock` вернет `Void`, а вы пытаетесь записать результаты его выполнения в константу `let spawn`. То есть по сути `let spawn = Void` - вряд ли это то, что вам нужно.

Вероятно, нужно что-то типа:

```
var spawn: SomeType!
SKAction.runBlock { _ in spawn = self.spawnPipes() }
```

Происходит такая штука потому, что мы можем возвращать из блока значение, не используя слово return, это сделано для упрощения синтаксиса, но нужно следить за типами, например:

```
let items = [SomeType]()
let filtered = items.filter { $0.type != SomeEnum.concretteType }
```

Тут слова return нет в принципе, мы можем его написать, но необязательно, во всех блоках тема, очевидно, та же, но это не всегда прозрачно.